# how get dynamic element value by id using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Jquery. And facing some issue while accessing dynamic element from my JSP using JQuery

1. It works fine for me when I tried below code:

   ```
   function getListElement(index)
   {
       document.getElementById('dataList['+index+'].firstName').value;
   }
   ```
2. Its not work when I tried below code:

   ```
   function getListElement(index)
   {
       $("#dataList["+index+"].firstName").val();
   }
   ```

Why 2nd point is not working  may I know  reason...... :(

Is there any other syntax to get that value....?

Thanks In Advance.....:)

Comment: Don't use arrays of id's. Id should be unique for each element. If you need an array, use name instead.

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Also, jQuery uses `[` and `]` as a selector, so it won't match an id with `[` in it.

Comment: And how do you call the getListElement function ?

Comment: Use class then index instead of so unusual IDs

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#dataList\\["+index+"\\]\\.firstName").val();
```

`[]` and `.` have special meaning in a selector.  You might consider simplifying your `id`s.

Comment: I think firstName is a class here, so it should not be escaped.

Comment: @Oliboy50 not what suggest `document.getElementById('dataList['+index+'].firstName')` which OP said works

Comment: Also worth noting that I believe `[]` characters are not valid within an `id`.  Most browsers may allow it, but they are invalid based on the html spec.